# Getting TypeError while downloading file from url using requests module

Tags: python

following is my code to download a zip file from NSE (National Stock Exchange, Mumbai, India) website.

```
import requests

url = r"https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2021/NOV/cm24NOV2021bhav.csv.zip"

resp = requests.get(url)

with open("bhavcopy.zip", "wb") as f:
    f.write(resp)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Response'
```

I am on Windows 10 OS and I am running this program from Anaconda IDE. How can I correct this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `resp.content` like here:

```
import requests

url = r"https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2021/NOV/cm24NOV2021bhav.csv.zip"

resp = requests.get(url)

with open("bhavcopy.zip", "wb") as f:
    f.write(resp.content)
```